# Laravel 4 - Models & One to Many

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to get my head around laravel models & one to many...

I have the following tables

```
ww_bookings
-----------------------------
booking_id
customer_id
quote_id

ww_quotes
-----------------------------
quote_id
etc
etc
etc
```

I'm using sentry for my auth and basically on a sucsessful login I want to find the id of the logged in user and then query the ww_bookings data WHERE customer_id = 'logged in user id'.

Once it's good all the bookings for the customer_id it then need to go and query ww_quotes for each booking found and bring back the data.

```
//Controller
BookingData::find(1)->quotes()->where('quote_id', '=', '1')->get();

//BookingData Model
class BookingData extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'ww_bookings';
protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';

public function quotes() {

  return $this->hasMany('QuoteData');

}


}

//QuoteData Model
class QuoteData extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'ww_quotes';

}
```

I get the following error:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ww_quotes.booking_data_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `ww_quotes` where `ww_quotes`.`booking_data_id` = 1 and `quote_id` = 1)

Can anyone help me out, it's been driving me crazy...

Hope it makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I see:

**Wrong relationship**
The problem is that `ww_quotes` schema/table should contain key that refers `ww_booking` schema/table - exactly in reverse.
Solution to this:

```
ww_bookings
-----------------------------
customer_id
quote_id

ww_quotes
-----------------------------
quote_id
booking_id
```

**Key will not match**
Key names that Eloquent generates and uses for relations will not match existing key names. If you specify them, Eloquent use them instead.

```
return $this->hasMany('QuoteData', 'booking_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for that Andre, but will that work because 1 customer could have multiple bookings against there customer_id??